# Migrating database project from VS2010 to VS 2017

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, migration

I am migrating a database project from VS 2010 .Net framework 2.0 to VS 2017 .Net framework 4.7.2 on MS build 15. While the project has been successfully migrated, I am getting compile time error which is caused because the db object does not exist. On looking further it seems there is a reference to master.dbschema file in VS 2010 which after migration was converted to master.dacpac but the reference path do not exist.

I have gone through a few of the articles and found that vstsdb is speficic to VS 2010 and primarily helps in deployment (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bahill/2009/02/20/deploying-your-database-project-without-vstsdb-installed/). The developers who worked on the project are long gone and I have no clue on how to fix this migration issue. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

I do not know if it helps but the source control we are using is GIT and CI is Bamboo.

Comment: It looks like you are adding SQL Compact Edition which is a SDF file.  So add the SDF per following website : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983322.aspx

Comment: I realise now that I should have explained the problem better. The migrated solution was not able to find the reference to master.dbschema and that was because, I believe, we do not have dbschema ref files in VS 2017. I had to remove that reference , right click reference > add database reference and select System database in options. This generated the necessary master.dacpac file. Seems we do not have dbschema ref files anymore. The solution now builds fine

Comment: Schema are often ignored is they are not found and errors not always generated.  So the VS2010 didn't report the schema issue while new improved 2017 does report the error that it is not found.